# Каким образом лучше передавать управление из функции в функцию в Телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

В сети полно обучалок на тему создания "Первого телеграмм бота на python", но я не нашел рекомендаций по созданию более-менее серьезных ботов с глубокими вложенными меню и т.д.
Использую библиотеку PyTelegrambotApi

Интересуют несколько вопросов:

- Каким образом лучше передавать управление из функции в функцию?
- С помощью @bot.message_handler? Или же bot.register_next_step_handler?
- Есть какие-то рекомендации по этой теме?

P.s. если у кого-то есть свои грамотно написанные боты с комментариями, поделитесь, пожалуйста, ссылкой.

Answer (score 0):

`@message_handler` - инициализация хэндлера.

`register_next_step_handler` - метод для "передачи управления" в другой хэндлер. Пример взятый с репозитория [PyTelegrambotApi](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py) (примеры ботов можно найти в конце этого же репозитория)
:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, """\
Hi there, I am Example bot.
What's your name?
""")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_name_step)


def process_name_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        name = message.text
        user = User(name)
        user_dict[chat_id] = user
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'How old are you?')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_age_step)
    except Exception as e:
bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops')
```